# parse a xml file with name spaces using j query

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml-parsing

Can any body help me to parse this [Xml File](http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/educategories.cat) file using jquery . This file contains name spaces and i am facing problem in parsing this.

this is the xml.

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<app:categories xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007" fixed="no" scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/educategories.cat">
<atom:category term="0" label="Primary & Secondary Education" xml:lang="en-US"/>
<atom:category term="1" label="Fine Arts" xml:lang="en-US">
<yt:parentCategory term="0"/>
</atom:category>
<atom:category term="2" label="Dance" xml:lang="en-US">
<yt:parentCategory term="1"/>
</atom:category>
<atom:category term="3" label="Dramatic Arts & Theater" xml:lang="en-US">
<yt:parentCategory term="1"/>
</atom:category>
<atom:category term="4" label="Music" xml:lang="en-US">
<yt:parentCategory term="1"/>
</atom:category>
<atom:category term="405" label="Social Work" xml:lang="en-US">
<yt:parentCategory term="375"/>
</atom:category>
<atom:category term="406" label="Sociology" xml:lang="en-US">
<yt:parentCategory term="375"/>
</atom:category>
</app:categories>
```

Comment: you need to post the code not just a link

Comment: it is the xml file. i dont know how to parse it , because i didnt parse xml in jquery, i need some sample or some help.

Comment: You need to show the XML in your question and not post some links.

Comment: how will the xml be loaded... are you using ajax if so whether your script will be in the same domain as the xml file's domain

Comment: i was using $.parseXML("xml ile path"). i am running my app on local server and file is also stored localy. ineed category label

Comment: The `$.parseXML` function doesn't take file paths. It takes XML. So you will need to first fetch the XML from your server.

Comment: i also tried  $.get('path to tha file', {}, function(xml) {}, "xml"); but dont able to get the elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have shown is invalid XML. You must replace the `&` with `&amp;`. There are online XML formatter sites such as [freeformatter.com](http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html) that might assist you in having valid XML.

Once you have valid XML you can parse it with an XML parser such as the `$.parseXML` function.

Here's an example of how you can retrieve all the category labels:

```
var xml = '<app:categories xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007" fixed="no" scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/educategories.cat"><atom:category term="0" label="Primary &amp; Secondary Education" xml:lang="en-US"/><atom:category term="1" label="Fine Arts" xml:lang="en-US"><yt:parentCategory term="0"/></atom:category><atom:category term="2" label="Dance" xml:lang="en-US"><yt:parentCategory term="1"/></atom:category><atom:category term="3" label="Dramatic Arts &amp; Theater" xml:lang="en-US"><yt:parentCategory term="1"/></atom:category><atom:category term="4" label="Music" xml:lang="en-US"><yt:parentCategory term="1"/></atom:category><atom:category term="405" label="Social Work" xml:lang="en-US"><yt:parentCategory term="375"/></atom:category><atom:category term="406" label="Sociology" xml:lang="en-US"><yt:parentCategory term="375"/></atom:category></app:categories>';    
var data = $.parseXML(xml);
var categories = $(data).find('category');
$.each(categories, function() {
    var label = $(this).attr('label');
    console.log(label);
});
```

If the XML is stored on your server you will need to first retrieve it using AJAX for example and then simply find the elements you are looking for:

```
$.get('/file.xml', function(xml) {
    var categories = $(xml).find('category');
    $.each(categories, function() {
        var label = $(this).attr('label');
        console.log(label);
    });
}, 'xml');
```

Note that in this case you don't need to call the `$.parseXML` function because jQuery will automatically call it for you before invoking the AJAX success callback and it will directly provide the parsed XML.

Comment: thankouy very much for your help, you helped me lot. it is perfectly working. i need to check my xml first with the formatter.